# Use previous backreference as name of named capture group

Tags: php, regex, pcre, regex-group, backreference

Is there a way to use a backreference to a previous capture group as the name of a *named capture group*? This may not be possible, if not, then that is a valid answer.

The following:

```
$data = 'description: some description';
preg_match("/([^:]+): (.*)/", $data, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Yields:

```
(
    [0] => description: some description
    [1] => description
    [2] => some description
)
```

My attempt using a backreference to the first capture group as a named capture group `(?<$1>.*)` tells me it's either not possible or I'm just not doing it correctly:

```
preg_match("/([^:]+): (?<$1>.*)/", $data, $matches);
```

Yields:

> Warning: preg_match(): Compilation failed: unrecognized character after (?< at offset 12

The desired result would be:

```
(
    [0] => description: some description
    [1] => description
    [description] => some description
)
```

This is simplified using `preg_match`.  When using `preg_match_all` I normally use:

```
$matches = array_combine($matches[1], $matches[2]);
```

But thought I might be slicker than that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In short, it is not possible, you can stick to the programming means you have been using so far.

Group names (that should [*consist of up to 32 alphanumeric characters and underscores, but must start with a non-digit*](https://www.pcre.org/original/doc/html/pcrepattern.html#SEC16)) are parsed at compile time, and a backreference value is only known at run-time. Note it is also a reason why you cannot use a backreference inside a lookbehind (altghough you clearly see that `/(x)y[a-z](?<!\1)/` is OK, the [PCRE regex engine sees otherwise](https://regex101.com/r/24m2lu/1) as it cannot infer the length of the lookbehind with a backreference).

Answer (score 3):

You already have an answer to the regex question (no), but for a different PHP based approach you could try using a callback.

```
preg_replace_callback($pattern, function($match) use (&$matches) {
    $matches[$match[1]] = $match[2];
}, $data);
```