# regex pattern ending sub group

Tags: php, regex, regex-group

I could have the following strings:
Case 1:

```
VIR RECU 998721687978
DE: Mrs PAUL SMITH
564
MOTIF: ANY REASON
```

or case 2:

```
VIR RECU 998721687978
DE: Mrs PAUL SMITH
564
```

The "MOTIF: ..." part can be missing from the string

I am looking for a regex to isolate substring of the 2 precedents.
So far I have: `^VIR\sRECU\s(\d+)\nDE:\s(.*)(\nMOTIF:\s(.*))` that work for well for the case 1 but not for the case 2. If I had a question mark after the 'motif' capturing group like `^VIR\sRECU\s(\d+)\nDE:\s(.*)(\nMOTIF:\s(.*))?` then this group is never isolated

I suppose the problem comes from the (.*) group, but cannot figure how to fix it.

Is it possible ? Or should I have 2 different regex, 1 for each case ?

I am using these regex on php with preg_math() function.

The results I want is `998721687978`, `Mrs PAUL SMITH
564` and `ANY REASON` values

Comment: So you just need `RECU` and `DE` values?

Comment: If so maybe https://regex101.com/r/WksB4s/2/ with https://stackoverflow.com/a/48817140/3783243 could work for you.

Comment: It's a bit unclear. Could you elaborate what your desired result is from both cases? As per @user3783243 his first comment. Anyway, try: `^VIR\sRECU\s(\d*)\nDE:\s(.*)\n.*(?:\nMOTIF:\s(.*))?`

Comment: @user3783243 yes I want thoses values

Comment: @JvdV I have edited my question to add the expected result

Comment: @MatMouth, so would `VIR RECU\s(\d+)\nDE:\s(.+)\n(.*)(?:\nMOTIF:\s(.*))?` get what you want? All 4 values in their own respective capture group?

Comment: @JvdV in the case 2, the content of the last line(564) is not captured with the "Mrs PAUL SMITH"

Comment: We will get there, try: `VIR RECU\s(\d+)\nDE:\s(.+\n.+)(?:\nMOTIF:\s(.+))?`. Two capture groups and an optional third

Comment: So `564` should be captured with new line?

Comment: yes but also all the MOTIF and its value

Comment: Maybe `^VIR\s+RECU\s+(\d+)\nDE:\s+([\s\S]*?)(\nMOTIF:\s+(.*))?$` will do? See https://regex101.com/r/jOA28N/1 and https://regex101.com/r/jOA28N/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
^VIR\s+RECU\s+(\d+)\nDE:\s+([\s\S]*?)(\nMOTIF:\s+(.*))?$
```

See a [regex test #1](https://regex101.com/r/jOA28N/1) and a [regex test #2](https://regex101.com/r/jOA28N/2)

**Regex details**

- `^` - start of string
- `VIR\s+RECU\s+` - `VIR`, 1+ whitespaces, `RECU` and again 1+ whitespaces
- `(\d+)` -  Group 1: one or more digits
- `\nDE:`  - a newline and `DE:` substring
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `([\s\S]*?)`  - Group 2: any 0+ chars, as few as possible
- `(\nMOTIF:\s+(.*))?` - an optional capturing group #3:

  - `\nMOTIF:` - newline and `MOTIF:` string
  - `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
  - `(.*)`  - Group 4: any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as many as possible
- `$` - end of string.